# Format a Mac address with TCL

Tags: string, macros, tcl, mac-address

Hello I am trying to use TCL in a program called Shorthand which is a text macro program. 
Anyway I am trying to use it to stip and reformat Mac Addresses. I can not figure out the function to split a string at a specified index integer. Here is what I have so far.

```
set DirtyMac [sh_set clipboard]
set HalfMac [string map { .  "" } $DirtyMac ]
set FullMac [string map { : "" } $HalfMac]
set ParsedMac [string map { " " "" } $FullMac]
if {[string length $ParsedMac] < 12 } {
return "Mac too short";
} elseif {[string length $ParsedMac] > 12 } {
return "Mac too long";
} else {
return [string map { " " "" } $ParsedMac]
}
```

That is to clean the Mac of all unwanted characters 
I have been trying

```
set Mac1 [linsert $ParsedMac 4 .]
return $Mac1;
```

or

```
set Mac1 [split [string is index $ParsedMac 4 ] "."]
return $Mac1;
```

Nothing is working... anything anyone can do to help would be great!

Ok so what I am trying to do is take a Mac address such as 11:22:33:44:55:66 or 1122.3344.5566 or 112233445566 and have the output be in one of the those 3 formats. I will ultimately write 3 different scripts that will be called based on the need of the output.

So for example
 I have the mac 1122.3344.5566 I want to turn it into 11:22:33:44:55:66

```
set DirtyMac "1122.3344.5566"
set ParsedMac [string map {. "" : "" " " ""} $DirtyMac]
scan $ParsedMac "%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s" a b c d e f
set FullMac [join $a $b $c $d $e $f  ":"]
return $FullMac;
```

OR

I have the mac 112233445566 I want to turn it into 1122.3344.5566

```
set DirtyMac "112233445566"
set ParsedMac [string map {. "" : "" " " ""} $DirtyMac]
scan $ParsedMac "%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s" a b c d e f
set FullMac [join $a $b $c $d $e $f  ":"]
return $FullMac;
```

lastly

I have the mac 1122.3344.5566 || 11:22:33:44:55:66 I want to turn it into 112233445566

```
set DirtyMac | Mac Address Input|
set ParsedMac [string map {. "" : "" " " ""} $DirtyMac] 
return $ParsedMac;
```

Comment: Note that MAC addresses may also be written with `-` as a separator. It's amazing what you learn from Wikipedia…

Comment: Yes, However on anything that I deal with it would only be ":" or "." so I guess that is a good thing for me. One less thing that I have to deal with. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can do the cleaning as a single step:

```
set ParsedMac [string map {. "" : "" " " ""} $DirtyMac]
```

Mind you, I'd actually be tempted to use a different cleaning method: removing all non-hex characters:

```
set ParsedMac [regsub -all {[^0-9a-fA-F]} $DirtyMac ""]
```

Secondly, splitting that string into 4-character pieces (note that I'm assuming you put the length checks in first) is actually best done with `scan`:

```
scan $ParsedMac "%4x%4x%4x" a b c
```

This extracts the four four-hex-digit characters and converts them into numbers. Alternatively, you can scan them as ordinary strings:

```
scan $ParsedMac "%4s%4s%4s" a b c
```

Then you'd need to do whatever you are looking to do with putting the pieces back together.

Comment: You could also use the character class `{[^[:xdigit:]]}` to remove non-hex digits

Comment: @Donal Fellows Ok so what I am trying to do is take a Mac address such as 11:22:33:44:55:66 or 1122.3344.5566 or 112233445566 and have the output be in one of the those 3 formats. I will ultimately write 3 different scripts that will be called based on the need of the output. I have edited what I am kinda going for in the original post... I know that it is still wrong but that is why i am here. While I am at it does anyone know any good books to teach myself tcl?

Comment: The character stripping can be done with just `string map`; it's a trivial string operation. Understanding the _sense_ of the MAC takes rather more code…